How do animals obtain energy by consuming other organisms?
This is a question I never really thought about much, but now that I have, I realized it wasn't explained in detail before. Maybe it is irrelevant, but how do animals get energy by consuming each other? Specifically,there is a certain text I am wondering about: "The hare uses a significant fraction of the assimilated energy just being a hare -- maintaining a high, constant body temperature, synthesizing proteins, and hopping about. This energy used (lost) is attributed to cellular respiration.The remainder goes into making more hare biomass by growth and reproduction."
This confuses me in several ways.

What differentiates "just being a hare" and the functions associated with that from growth and reproduction? Don't all of those processes include cellular respiration?
Later in the article, it states that the conversion of the assimilated energy into new tissues is what provides food for foxes. How does this happen? Is energy stored after conversion?
Basically, I don't exactly know how to word my question, but hopefully this provides enough information. If not, please let me know. Thanks!
Edit: Also, please keep in mind that I just started high school and don't have a good grasp on this concept yet, so it is likely I won't understand some responses.


"Energy" in foods come from macronutrients: fats, carbohydrates, and proteins. These are the primary physical components making up the mass of an organism (the "hare biomass by growth"). Making these molecules requires a lot of energy; some of that energy becomes stored in chemical bonds. It's possible to retrieve some of that energy by breaking them down into their component parts, all the way down to carbon dioxide, water, and nitrogenous wastes.
If you eat a hare, you digest the proteins, carbohydrates, and fats that make up the structure and energy storage of the hare.

How does cell division and growth fit into that, if at all?

@user386598 Well, an organism of growing and dividing cells is going to be made up of more and more of the organic molecules of life.

This makes sense, thank you.
